# Time interval between Close_time and Open_time

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, intervals

I have a question in SQL.
I use MS SQL SERVER 2012
I need to calculate the difference between Close_time and Open_time.
How can I make the range of years-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds.
**For Example:

```
Start_time : 2017:01.01 20:30:15
Close_time : 2018.02.05  22:58:35
Output: 0001:01:04 02:28:20**
```

I know that this is not correct, because it is not a time interval.

```
Select Name,
Convert(VARCHAR,CAST(AVG(CAST(CAST(CLOSE_TIME as datetime) - CAST(OPEN_TIME  as datetime)as float)) as datetime), 120)as TM
From [dbo].[INCIDENTS]
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: This can vary according to whether or not you are using MySQL, SQL-Server, etc.  Please update your Question to reflect which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests SQL Server.  You can just subtract the values:

```
SELECT CAST(CLOSE_TIME as datetime) - CAST(OPEN_TIME as datetime)
```

Note:  You should really be storing such fields as date/time values.  If you are, just subtract them:

```
SELECT (CLOSE_TIME - OPEN_TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a UDF. This Table-Valued-Function is precise and performant.

I added a field called `ELAPSED` which is your desired format, but I also left Years, Months, Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds.  These can be removed if desired

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,DateBeg datetime,DateEnd datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'2017-01-01 20:30:15','2018-02-05 22:58:35')

Select A.*
      ,B.Elapsed
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Date-Elapsed](A.DateBeg,A.DateEnd) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  DateBeg                   DateEnd                     Elapsed
1   2017-01-01 20:30:15.000   2018-02-05 22:58:35.000     0001:01:04 02:28:20
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Date-Elapsed] (@D1 DateTime,@D2 DateTime)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cteBN(N)   as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cteRN(R)   as (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 From cteBN a,cteBN b,cteBN c),
         cteYY(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(YY,R,@D1))From cteRN R Where DateAdd(YY,R,@D1)<=@D2),
         cteMM(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MM,R,D))  From (Select Top 12 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteYY P Where DateAdd(MM,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteDD(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(DD,R,D))  From (Select Top 31 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMM P Where DateAdd(DD,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteHH(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(HH,R,D))  From (Select Top 24 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteDD P Where DateAdd(HH,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteMI(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MI,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteHH P Where DateAdd(MI,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteSS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(SS,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMI P Where DateAdd(SS,R,D)<=@D2)

    Select [Years]   = cteYY.N
          ,[Months]  = cteMM.N
          ,[Days]    = cteDD.N
          ,[Hours]   = cteHH.N
          ,[Minutes] = cteMI.N
          ,[Seconds] = cteSS.N
          ,[Elapsed] = Format(cteYY.N,'0000')+':'+Format(cteMM.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteDD.N,'00')+' '+Format(cteHH.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteMI.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteSS.N,'00')
     From  cteYY,cteMM,cteDD,cteHH,cteMI,cteSS
)
--Max 1000 years
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Date-Elapsed] ('1991-09-12 21:00:00.000',GetDate())
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Date-Elapsed] ('2017-01-01 20:30:15','2018-02-05 22:58:35')
```

---

> **EDIT - For a Scalar-Valued Function**

**Example**

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Elapsed] ('2017-01-01 20:30:15','2018-02-05 22:58:35')
```

**Returns**

```
0001:01:04 02:28:20
```

**The Scalar Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Elapsed] (@D1 DateTime,@D2 DateTime)
Returns varchar(100)
AS 
Begin
    Declare @RetVal varchar(100)
    ;with cteBN(N)   as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
          cteRN(R)   as (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 From cteBN a,cteBN b,cteBN c),
          cteYY(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(YY,R,@D1))From cteRN R Where DateAdd(YY,R,@D1)<=@D2),
          cteMM(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MM,R,D))  From (Select Top 12 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteYY P Where DateAdd(MM,R,D)<=@D2),
          cteDD(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(DD,R,D))  From (Select Top 31 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMM P Where DateAdd(DD,R,D)<=@D2),
          cteHH(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(HH,R,D))  From (Select Top 24 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteDD P Where DateAdd(HH,R,D)<=@D2),
          cteMI(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MI,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteHH P Where DateAdd(MI,R,D)<=@D2),
          cteSS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(SS,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMI P Where DateAdd(SS,R,D)<=@D2)

    Select @RetVal = Format(cteYY.N,'0000')+':'+Format(cteMM.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteDD.N,'00')+' '+Format(cteHH.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteMI.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteSS.N,'00')
     From  cteYY,cteMM,cteDD,cteHH,cteMI,cteSS

    Return @RetVal

End
```